# Edit Ruby Gem locally and execute gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

For a project I'm working on, I have to do some work on an existing Ruby Gem. I haven't got much previous experience with Ruby and am struggling with a few aspects.

I have the repository cloned locally. I need to edit the current files in the /lib/ directory, which I can do. Is it possible for me to compile the edited files into a Gem and run this Gem? Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes! You can include the gem in a local project and point the Gemfile to your local directory:

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'my_local_gem', path: '/absolute/path/to/your/gem'
```

Then edit the gem, run your local program and see the changes.

Additionally, you don't always have to clone a whole gem, you can install it via rubygems and use `bundle open <gem_name>`  to open the gem's contents in your supplied editor.

[I have written a post describing just that and more here](http://jakeyesbeck.com/2015/08/16/gems-are-not-magic/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I'm still a little unclear on a few aspects. 

I've creted my_gem. Do I alter the Gemfile of my_gem or the Gemfile of the gem that I would like to alter?

Comment: You alter the Gemfile of the place where you **include** `my_gem`, not the Gemfile in the `my_gem` directory.